# i have generated a string from decoder what is best practice to split string to unequal groups at a certain range

Tags: python-3.x

s='00EF0100F001001503'

Split or grouping must have 2 and 1 byte in following sequence.

00EF

01

00F0

01

0015

03

Comment: How do you know that's where it should be split? Does `s` change? When `s` changes, are the splits always at the same location?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.